# Pass Foreignkey from User Input to DB

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to have user input the data and store into DB and map with the other data.

Model:

```
class Code(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Within the Model, there is another class

```
class Pull(models.Model):
  code_pull = models.ForeignKey(Code, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

How to display to call in the Form and View, so that data is pass when user input the data in the input field.

Form

```
class Code_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Code
        fields = ('name',)

class Pull_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pull
        fields = ('code_pull', 'data1', 'prefix',)
        #Inital Value is NULL
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Pull_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['code_pull'].queryset = CODE.objects.none()
        if 'code_pull' in self.data:
            c = self.data.get('code_pull')
            self.fields['code_pull'].queryset = CODE.objects.filter(name=c)
            #print(self.fields['code_pull'].queryset)
```

I updated the code for the FORM, so that it initial the value from the CODE_form, Still Error, as the code field is empty

Here is the VIEW:

```
def InputData(request, *args, **kwargs):
   form = Pull_Form(request.POST or None)
      if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
            data_add = form.save(commit=False)
            data_add.code = form.cleaned_data['code_pull']
            data_add.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form })
```

ERROR: Not able to add the data as the field for the `code` is not selected when submitting the form. 
ERROR CODE: `code - Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

```
{{ messages }}
<form id="form1" class="post-form" role=form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
<input id="code_pull" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="4" required></input>
<label for="code_pull">Code</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't see an error message there, it's just the string representation of the Django `messages` object, which you've included in your HTML. You should loop through the messages and display each one individually.

Comment: Ok, How to send the form data to store to DB?, some reason I don't see it being stored.. it just redirect to same page and clear the data..

Comment: I think my view is incorrect, as I don't get any result from the log nor print statement

Answer (score 0):

Django forms use the `name` attribute in HTML controls to capture form data.

```
<input id="code" name="code" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="4" required></input>
```

I only added `name="code"`. this should make it work.

Comment: With my current code, how to fetch the stored value from the DB?

Comment: Now, I'm getting error: code in my {{ message}} `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`